# Salesforce Quickbooks Oauth2.0 Integration

Tags: apex, rest-api, integration, quickbooks, quickbooks-api

I am working on integrating Salesforce with Quickbooks using Oauth 2.0. I am able to get Access token and Refresh token with the help of client_d and consumer_secret. The scope of access token is - com.intuit.quickbooks.accounting. The problem is when I use the fetched Access Token to make API request via Postman, it is working fine. But when I tried to make an API call from Apex class I get the following error:

> General Authentication ErrorAuthenticationErrorGeneral: SRV-110-Authentication Failure , statusCode: 401

I am using following code to make the API call :

```
    String accessToken = '<access_token>';    
    String endPoint = 'https://sandbox-quickbooks.api.intuit.com/v3/company/<Sandbox_Id>/invoice/145?minorversion=4';
    HttpRequest httpReq = new HttpRequest();
    HttpResponse httpRes = new HttpResponse();
    Http http = new Http();
    httpReq.setMethod('GET');
    httpReq.setEndPoint(endPoint);
    httpReq.setHeader('Accept','*/*');
    httpReq.setHeader('Content-Type','application/json');
    httpReq.setHeader('charset','UTF-8');
    httpReq.setHeader('Authorization' , 'Bearer '+accessToken);
    httpRes = http.send(httpReq);
```

Can anyone please let me know what I am doing wrong. Thanks in advance.

PS: I have edited the code. The above code is working fine.

Comment: 401 Unauthorized - Similar to 403 Forbidden, but specifically for use when authentication is required and has failed or has not yet been provided. The response must include a WWW-Authenticate header field containing a challenge applicable to the requested resource. 401 semantically means "unauthenticated", i.e. the user does not have the necessary credentials.
Note: Some sites issue HTTP 401 when an IP address is banned from the website (usually the website domain) and that specific address is refused permission to access a website.

Comment: Are you sure your `accessToken` is valid?

Comment: Yes @Adrian , I am able to make API calls via POSTMAN using the same accessToken. So I guess the accessToken is valid :).

Comment: Compare what headers you are using in Postman to what you use in Apex.

Comment: @Adrian I am using the same headers. You can see the screenshot from postman here - https://goo.gl/ctB4TS

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got it.... I was passing Basic instead of Bearer in the Authorization header. I have edited to code snippet in my question!!

Comment: i understand your answer, however, you might want to include what you changed in your answer (code snippet), just for completeness sake =) . And you can then accept your answer (24-48 hrs i think)

Comment: Better to leave the answer & let the OP self accept than to delete it & have the question float around the stack, getting ghost bumps from @commmunity.